# Get size of data transferred by REST Web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am using REST Web Services to upload a java object from a client to a server. How can I know the actual size of the data transferred per web service call?

I use Java 1.7, Jersey.

Part of the client code is below:

```
ClientResponse response = service.path(SERVER_PATH).path(myWebServiceMethod)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, myJavaObject);
```

Comment: Is this 'object' encoded, for example in JSON or XML?

Comment: Yes I think it's encoded in JSON, see the edit of the client code